# WinGPG: "Assign 'Ctrl+Alt+E' to 'Encrypt files/clipboard' failed."

Tags: windows, system-administration

I am trying to install WinGPG For Windows 32/64bit version from [scand](https://scand.com/products/wingpg/)

After download and install, I click the lock icon to open WinGPG and I see 4 errors starting with: "Assign 'Ctrl+Alt+E' to 'Encrypt files/clipboard' failed."

The other 3 are similar errors, just different keybinds.

I click ok through all 4 errors and then the program quits.

I cannot find anything about this online, has anyone else resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when trying to launch WinGPG when it was already running.  You should see WinGPG in your system tray and can open it that way.  If not in system tray, open up Task Manager, end all the WinGPG.exe processes, and then try to open WinGPG again